# Creating two rectangles on top of each other that resize proportionally

Tags: wpf

EDIT: I made my example screen grabs more illustrative. They were conflicting with the text description.

I am a complete WPF newbie.

I want to have a thin rectangle with a dividing line that will resize as I expand and contract the window. Since I need to color the rectangle differently above and below the line I thought to do this with one rectangle overlaid on top of the other.

I can get a single rectangle that fills up the xaml control top to bottom ( called tallRectangle ) to resize properly with the window, but I can't figure out how to extend that behavior to the second rectangle:

```
<Grid>
    <Rectangle x:Name="tallRectangle" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="23,0,0,0" Stroke="Black" Width="56"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="halfRectangle" Fill="#FF757576" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="84,136,0,0" Stroke="Black" Width="53" StrokeThickness="0" Stretch="Fill" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Rectangle.LayoutTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Rectangle.LayoutTransform>
        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
    </Rectangle>
</Grid>
```

I wish the second one, halfRectangle, to be half the size of the first, but to also scale larger and smaller if the window is resized. But I don't know how to make it do that.

Here is how it starts out:

[image]

When I make the window smaller, the top of the second rectangle stays static:

[image]

I would like the second rectangle to resize itself proportionally as well, like the orange outline in this:

[image]

This is only a very first step to what I'd like to have eventually, but I hope once I understand how to get that behavior in the second rectangle I'd be able to figure out the remainder of it.

Eventually I'd need to set that second rectangle to be a percentage of the height of the first, and I'd also need to add a variable number of hash marks to the first rectangle dynamically, at variable positions. It seems that once I understand how to get that second rectangle resizing, I'd be able to figure out the hash marks too.

EDIT: Once the grid structure is in place as explained in the answer to this question, the code behind can be modified to dynamically set the ratio, for example:

```
    Dim realDepth = 8000
    Dim divideDepth = 2600

    Dim realScreenHeight = topRectangle.Height.Value + bottomRectangle.Height.Value
    Dim realHeightToScreenRatio = realScreenHeight / realDepth
    Dim divideScreenPoint = divideDepth * realHeightToScreenRatio

    topRectangle.Height = New GridLength(divideScreenPoint, GridUnitType.Star)
    bottomRectangle.Height = New GridLength(realScreenHeight - topRectangle.Height.Value, GridUnitType.Star)
```

The magic sprinkles is the second parameter to GridLength in order to preserve the dynamic resizing of the row's height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are already using a Grid, why not define two equally sized rows:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Grid.RowSpan="2" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Stroke="Black" Width="56"/>
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Fill="#FF757576" Stroke="Black" Width="56"/>
</Grid>
```

---

If you need to set the ratio of the row heights at runtime, you can simply assign a name to each row

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition x:Name="row1"/>
        <RowDefinition x:Name="row2"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Grid.RowSpan="2" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Stroke="Black" Width="56"/>
    <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Fill="#FF757576" Stroke="Black" Width="56"/>
</Grid>
```

and change their relative heights like this:

```
row1.Height = new GridLength(2, GridUnitType.Star); // 2/5
row2.Height = new GridLength(3, GridUnitType.Star); // 3/5
```

Comment: Okay, I can see how that would help because the grid would take care of resizing its cells and the elements within. However, this answer made me realize that my example pictures were bad - I actually need the two rectangles overlaid or stacked on each other. I imagine I can somehow set a margin / buffer that would maintain the relative ratio between the two, but I can't figure out what would do that trick. The margins seem to not be dynamic.

Comment: See the updated answer. Not sure if the second one should actually be narrower than the first one.

Comment: They should be the same size - that was just some bad dragging on my part. And wow - that works like magic for equal sizes. Is it possible to do this for any proportion, by setting the height of the rows? I'm going to try that out now since that is where I need to end up.

Comment: This answer works for setting the heights of the rows once, but it does not work if you try to set the row height at run time, in the same fashion my initial attempt did not work. I did not realize this before I accepted the answer. Just leaving this note here for anybody who reads the answer! I will reformulate a question to be more specific about this.